# Error to load module btusb with kernel 4.10.0-20-generic

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth

I have the follow problem.
I need to recompile the module btusb to able the bluetooth with this [patch](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/wiki/Get-bluetooth-working-in-Linux-kernel--with-mt7630e)
When I finally run the patch the module didn't loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             557056  10 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm
```

I did try to load the module manually and give me this error:

```
$ sudo modprobe btusb
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'btusb': Exec format error
```

The last thing I did try was compile and load the vanilla code but displayed the same error.

Can be a bug in the source code from btusb?
If the answer is yes, I will to report the bug on launchpad, but I posted here first to be sure. I gave more info [here](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/issues/66)

Thanks for advanced.

Update:
more info about the module:

```
$ modinfo btusb | egrep 'filename|vermagic'
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
vermagic:       4.10.8 SMP mod_unload
```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `modinfo btusb | egrep 'filename|vermagic'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go back to the drivers/bluetooth directory of your source code and then

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config ./
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe -v btusb
```

The error occurred because the source code was compiled on the wrong kernel header.  The `modinfo` results confirm this as the vermagic info(kernel 4.10.8) doesn't match the filename info(4.10.0-20)

Comment: Two things: in line two it's $(uname -r) as well? and in the line five it's a "cd" or something?

Comment: Fixed with last edit

Comment: It works! thank you! (I hope you can help into the patch as well)

Comment: cp: cannot stat 'btusb.ko': No such file or directory
modprobe: FATAL: Module btusb not found.

Comment: @MichaelPaccione Please ask your own question as this was a special case