# How do I get my bluetooth device working?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, 19.04

I need some help with a bluetooth problem. I am unable to use a USB bluetooth device. The bluetooth UI just says there is no adapter.

I am running ubuntu 19.04 and everything is up to date.

I have this device as per lsusb,

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

dmesg | grep Bluetooth

```
[ 6.137963] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 6.137977] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 6.137980] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 6.137982] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 6.137984] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 8.208995] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[ 10.224994] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2007 tx timeout
[ 15.063638] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 15.063639] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 15.063642] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1069.727317] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[ 1071.743434] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2007 tx timeout
[ 1346.401282] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[ 1348.417451] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2007 tx timeout
[ 1487.968981] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[ 1489.984757] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2007 tx timeout
[ 2258.267934] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[ 2260.287907] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2007 tx timeout
```

hciconfig -a hci0

```
hci0: Type: Primary Bus: USB
BD Address: 33:03:30:09:E8:9D ACL MTU: 360:4 SCO MTU: 0:0
DOWN 
RX bytes:3318 acl:0 sco:0 events:168 errors:0
TX bytes:2208 acl:0 sco:0 commands:180 errors:0
Features: 0xff 0xff 0xcd 0xfa 0xdb 0xbf 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

sudo hciconfig hci0 up

```
Can't init device hci0: Operation not supported (95)
```

I'm not sure what else to do here?

Interestingly enough I purchased this device because it said it would work with a raspberry pi, so I thought that would mean it would work with other linux distros too. And it is mentioned here,

https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Bluetooth_adapters

Answer (score 8):

Apparently there are a lot of fake CSR dongles. Linux has code to deal with it, but it doesn't seem to work with all fake dongles. The fake ones have a bad return code for bt *Delete Stored Link Key* function. To see if this is the case for you, run:

```
sudo btmon
```

in one terminal, and while it's running, run

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

and `btmon` should show an error after *Delete Stored Link Key* like :

```
Status: Unsupported Feature or Parameter Value
```

To fix this, I edited `btusb.c` and recompiled the `btusb.ko` kernel module. To get the source code into the current directory:

```
apt-get source linux
```

To build and install, see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915235/error-to-load-module-btusb-with-kernel-4-10-0-20-generic). You should probably back up `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko` before overwriting it.

I had to comment out 2 `if` statements in `btusb.c` to force the conditional code to run (you can try fixing `if` statements if you're able), as such:

```
/* Fake CSR devices with broken commands */
// if (bcdDevice <= 0x100 || bcdDevice == 0x134)
```

and

```
/* Detect controllers which aren't real CSR ones. */
/* if (le16_to_cpu(rp->manufacturer) != 10 ||
    le16_to_cpu(rp->lmp_subver) == 0x0c5c) */  {
```

This hacked `btusb` mod now assumes any CSR is fake, and mine is working. I guess the new clones are using different numbers. Unfortunately I'll have to copy or rebuild `btusb.ko` whenever I get a new kernel.

Comment: This works flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

After I installed 19.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 900 I was not able to turn on the bluetooth adapter. I tried some solutions that were suggested for older versions of Ubuntu, none worked.

When I used these commands to reload the kernel module my problem got fixed.

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

It seems that I need to do this after each reboot.

Comment: Doesn't worked on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. The Bluetooth device is reported by `lsusb` as `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp.`. I have Dell Latitude 5410 (09A0) laptop.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for you help answer user1020113 and damadam.

I got a couple of Bluetooth dongles which turned out to be fake and fixed them in the same way that you described here. It enables to system to take on any dongle and work with it.

It is very simple. I will try put everything together in simple-to-follow way.

Since you will be recompiling the btcusb.ko module, you will need to get the Linux source code so make sure that you are able to download the source code. To check that you are able to download the source code, run  the following command:

```
software-properties-gtk and click the "source code" checkbox.
```

Once you are sure that you are set to download the source code, execute the following command. It will download the source code into your current directory, so make sure you are in a directory where you want this to be built.

```
apt source linux
```

This should create a directory `$SOURCEDIR` of the same name as your kernel version and unpacks the source code into it.

Move to the directory in the current path:

```
cd $SOURCEDIR/drivers/bluetooth
```

Run the following:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/.config ./
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.bak 
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe -v btusb
```

If anything untoward happens, the above code has backed up the original btusb.ko to btusb.ko.bak so you can always revert it back.

Et voila. Enjoy! But remember, a fake device will act like a fake device.

Comment: Is this another solution compare to the existing one? Something you have to do after? before?

Answer (score 0):

The driver patching answers are awesome. I got tired of the manual work on every update though. So I made a script!
Please note that the code below will not work copy & pasted because of tab/space sensitive indentation in the inline patch. Use this gist instead: https://gist.github.com/andsens/10abada615b69b8ca9b1f2b439288b30

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168123/how-do-i-get-my-bluetooth-device-working/1192200#1192200
set -e

SCRIPTDIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

main() {
  local kernver
  kernver=$(uname -r)
  sudo apt update
  rm -rf "$SCRIPTDIR"/linux{-,_}*
  apt source linux

  local drvdir="$SCRIPTDIR/linux-${kernver/%-*}/drivers/bluetooth"
  patch -d "$drvdir" <<<"--- btusb.c    2021-01-28 10:00:00.000000000 +0000
+++ btusb.c 2021-01-28 10:00:00.000000000 +0000
@@ -1642,8 +1642,8 @@
    rp = (struct hci_rp_read_local_version *)skb->data;

    /* Detect controllers which aren't real CSR ones. */
-   if (le16_to_cpu(rp->manufacturer) != 10 ||
-       le16_to_cpu(rp->lmp_subver) == 0x0c5c) {
+   /* if (le16_to_cpu(rp->manufacturer) != 10 ||
+       le16_to_cpu(rp->lmp_subver) == 0x0c5c) */ {
        /* Clear the reset quirk since this is not an actual
         * early Bluetooth 1.1 device from CSR.
         */
@@ -3899,7 +3899,7 @@
            set_bit(HCI_QUIRK_RESET_ON_CLOSE, &hdev->quirks);

        /* Fake CSR devices with broken commands */
-       if (bcdDevice <= 0x100 || bcdDevice == 0x134)
+       // if (bcdDevice <= 0x100 || bcdDevice == 0x134)
            hdev->setup = btusb_setup_csr;

        set_bit(HCI_QUIRK_SIMULTANEOUS_DISCOVERY, &hdev->quirks);
"
  make -C "/lib/modules/$kernver/build" M="$drvdir" clean
  cp "/usr/src/linux-headers-$kernver/.config" "$drvdir/"
  cp "/usr/src/linux-headers-$kernver/Module.symvers" "$drvdir/Module.symvers"
  make -C "/lib/modules/$kernver/build" M="$drvdir" modules

  local backupdir="$SCRIPTDIR/backup/$kernver"
  mkdir -p "$backupdir"
  sudo cp "/lib/modules/$kernver/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko" "$backupdir/btusb.ko"

  sudo cp "$drvdir/btusb.ko" "/lib/modules/$kernver/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko"
  sudo modprobe -r btusb
  sudo modprobe -v btusb
}

main "$@"
```